# UIBezierPath Clipping Background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath

I'm trying to clip a rect with a round rect because the width of the rect could be such that only part of the corner needs to be drawn. There will always be a background rounded rect.

I've got the following, the fill colour is clipped, but I also get a grey background to the clipping. Is there something I need to do to get rid of this?

```
// Cell
UIBezierPath *cell = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 133, 55) cornerRadius:10];
[[UIColor greyColor] setFill];
[cell fill];

// Level
UIBezierPath *level = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 129, 55)];
[level fill];

UIBezierPath *clipPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 133, 55) cornerRadius:10];
clipPath.usesEvenOddFillRule = YES;

CGContextSaveGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()); {
    [clipPath addClip];
    [color setFill];
    [level fill];
} CGContextRestoreGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

UIBezierPath *contact = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(135, 19, 5, 17) byRoundingCorners: UIRectCornerTopRight | UIRectCornerBottomRight cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(2.5, 2.5)];
[color setFill];
[contact fill];
```

Comment: As far as I can see you are filling with grey before you clip.

Comment: doh you're quite right the extra `[level fill];` shouldn't have been there. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the grey fill doesn't get clipped is because it happens before the clip is added to the context.

You are both doing `[level fill];` before and after clipping. Remove the one before the clipping and it should work.